# Strange Array Behavior in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to build an array and I am looping through the values of an XML document, I have everything pulling out great using xpath, here's my code:

```
    function parseAccountIds($xml) {

    $arr = array();

    foreach($xml->entry as $k => $v) {

        $acctName = $v->title;

        $prop = $v->xpath('dxp:property');
        foreach($prop as $k1 => $v1) {
            if($v1->attributes()->name == "ga:accountId")
                $acctId = (string) $v1->attributes()->value;
            else if($v1->attributes()->name == "ga:profileId")
                $profileId = (string) $v1->attributes()->value; 
        }

        echo "profile id ".$profileId;

        echo "<BR>";    

        echo "acctName ".$acctName;

        echo "<BR>";    

        $subArray = array($acctName => $profileId);

        print_r($subArray);

        $arr[] = array($acctId => $subArray);

    }

    print_r($arr);

    return json_encode($arr);

}
```

The most important bit is where I print_r subArray. I can see acctName and profileId print, but then subArray is empty. For Example:

```
profile id 45580
acctName accountName1
Array
(
)
profile id 4300
acctName accountName2
Array
(
)
profile id 4338
acctName accountName3
Array
(
)
```

How are these values not being inserted? I've been looking at the code for a while now, and I'm a bit confused.

Any suggestions would really help,
Thanks!

Comment: Certainly this should not be possible... do you get any errors? Do you run with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Comment: Thats a good call, turned it on but I'm not seeing any errors

Comment: Throw in the following line immediately after assigning $subArray: var_dump( $profileId, $acctName, $subArray );

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured it out $v->title was a SimpleXMLObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v->title is actually a SimpleXMLObject still!

I forgot to cast it as a string, when I tried to make it the index in the array, it freaked out, geez I spent a whole hour on this!

Thanks for your suggestions guys :P

Comment: I though print_r forces standard objects such as XML or Class object to strings if possible.
Only var_dump() actually returns "variable type/name" + "value".
Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: If this is the case, Matt's suggestion would have resolved the problem. I actually tried putting the acctname as the value instead of the index, and it printed SimpleXMLObject

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $subArray[$acctName] = $profileId;
```

instead of

```
$subArray = array($acctName => $profileId);
```